# Swift/Foundation: Inconsistent > and < operators of Measurement

Tags: swift, operator-keyword, comparable, foundation, measurement

`Foundation.Measurement` implements `>` and `<` operators with these signatures:

```swift
static func > (
    lhs: Measurement<UnitType>,
    rhs: Measurement<UnitType>
) -> Bool
```

(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement/2883205)

```swift
static func < <LeftHandSideType, RightHandSideType>(
    lhs: Measurement<LeftHandSideType>,
    rhs: Measurement<RightHandSideType>
) -> Bool where LeftHandSideType: Unit, RightHandSideType: Unit
```

(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement/2293618)

Why would they differ?

It seems like they didn’t bother implementing `>`:

> This is the default implementation of the greater-than operator (>) for any type that conforms to Comparable.

It seems they went ahead and just implemented `<`, not `>`–using a different signature.

Why does the `<` operator allow different unit types for `lhs` and `rhs`? Who would want to compare apples and oranges? I would expect:

```swift
static func < (
    lhs: Measurement<UnitType>,
    rhs: Measurement<UnitType>
) -> Bool
```

Comment: My guess is that is because you can create custom `Unit`'s via `init(symbol: String)` which means that the type cannot be known at compile time to constrain it on a generic function. But it's only an assumption, maybe someone else is more knowledgable on the subject and can shed some light.

Comment: Btw if you try to compare different units you get a fatal error (the documentation gives a vague hint about that: _true if the measurements **can be compared** and the lhs is less than the rhs converted value._)

Comment: Also, the generic seems to be working fine if you try to compare measurements with concrete subclasses of `Unit` (comparing `UnitMass` with `UnitAngle` for example)

Comment: When conforming a type to `Comparable` you only need to implement `<`less than operator. Of course you meed to conform your type to `Equatable` as well `==`. The other operators like `>`, `<=` and `>=` they have a default implementation automatically synthesised

Comment: Regarding the last question I agree they should have added a constrain where `LeftHandSideType == RightHandSideType`

Comment: @LeoDabus Under “Comparable Requirements” https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable#topics lists both > and <: `static func < (Self, Self) -> Bool` `static func > (Self, Self) -> Bool`

Comment: @MichaelGillen I am pretty sure all you need is to implement `<` you can try it yourself.  It says `Required` but it does say that  `Default implementations provided.` Note that even `<`  is not required anymore for simple structures

Comment: @MichaelGillen **Conforming to the Comparable Protocol
Types with Comparable conformance implement the less-than operator (<) and the equal-to operator (==). These two operations impose a strict total order on the values of a type, in which exactly one of the following must be true for any two values a and b:**

Comment: To add Comparable conformance to your custom types, define the < and == operators as static methods of your types. The == operator is a requirement of the Equatable protocol, which Comparable extends—see that protocol’s documentation for more information about equality in Swift. **Because default implementations of the remainder of the relational operators are provided by the standard library, you’ll be able to use !=, >, <=, and >= with instances of your type without any further code.**

Comment: I see, so even without their LeftHandSideType/RightHandSideType implementation of `<` there would have been a `<` operator. One that would have worked exactly like the `>` operator. Shame.